# Error when trying to run join command in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join two fields in SQL with the below command;

```
SELECT    [NUM] & [ITEMNUM] AS LINKCODE
FROM       mydatabase
```

When I run this I get the error;

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'O00000001' to data type int.
```

This is probably something easy but I am quite new to SQL. Any help would be appreciated :)

Thank you.

Comment: What is the intention of `[NUM] & [ITEMNUM]`? Are you trying to concatenate strings? `&` is [bitwise and](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx).

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: JOIN is SQL has a very specific meaning that is very different than how you just used the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just add a number and a string together. You have to bring them on the same data type first. Cast to `varchar` first

```
SELECT cast([NUM] as varchar) + [ITEMNUM] AS LINKCODE
FROM mydatabase
```

Comment: Only if it's a SQL Server (it is probably is due to the stupid [] andthe error message), otherwise "+" is a numeric oerator and not a string concat :-)  "&" is a BITAND, isn't it?

Comment: Yup. More about SQL Server Precedence can be found here: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). Implicit conversions are only possible from bottom to top. If you want to convert something from top to bottom you have to do it explicitly using cast or convert.

Comment: What if one of this columns is NULL?

Comment: @veljasije: Then the result would be `null`. If not intended that should be wrapped in a `isnull()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2012+ you can use

```
SELECT CONCAT([NUM],[ITEMNUM]) AS LINKCODE
FROM  mytable
```

This treats `NULL` as empty string and does the casting of numeric values to string.

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate two columns which might be null, overall result can be NULL like this:

```
SELECT NULL + [Something]
```

which result as NULL. So, your example need to contains some NULL handling method:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(cast([NUM] as varchar), SPACE(0)) + ISNULL(CAST([ITEMNUM] as VARCHAR), SPACE(0)) AS LINKCODE
FROM mydatabase
```